# Base change of a finite morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, galois-representations, schemes, resolution-of-singularities

Let $X$, $Y$, $Z$ be integral schemes of finite type over a field $K$ (i.e., locally affine opens are finitely-generated algebras over $K$). Suppose we have the following condition$\colon$

$f \colon Y \to X$ is finite.

We consider a dominant morphism $g \colon Z \to X$.

### Q. Suppose that ${\cal O}_Y \cap {\cal O}_Z = {\cal O}_X$. Then is it possble that $Y \times_X Z$ is *not* integral while $Y \times_X \eta_Z$ being integral ?

As in the answer below in the case $Y = Z$, there is an example as $Y$ being a normalisation of $X$.

Comment: Let $X$ be a scheme that is reduced but not normal, e.g., $\text{Spec}\ k[u,v]/\langle u^2 - v^3\rangle$ in characteristic $\neq 2,3.$  Denote by $X^{\text{nor}}\to X$ the normalization, and denote by $Z\subset X$ the non-normal locus. Define both $f:Y\to X$ and $g:Z\to X$ to equal the normalization morphism (this is a finite type morphism by a corollary of the Noether normalization theorem).  Then the morphism $X^\text{nor}\times_X X^{\text{nor}} \to X$ is an isomorphism away from $Z$, but the scheme is nonreduced over $Z$.

Comment: The closed set where $X$ is not normal should not have been denoted by $Z$ (which is the name for the second morphism).  I will correct this in an answer below.

Comment: Then, given a finite morphism $f \colon Y \to X$, is it true that such dominant $f \colon Z \to X$ as the fibre product $Y \times_X Z＄is NOT integral

Comment: I am writing that into the answer at this moment.

Comment: When you wrote "linearly independent", did you mean "linearly disjoint" as in field theory / Galois theory?  The identity map of fields, $\text{Id}:k\rightarrow k,$ is linearly disjoint from every other field extension, $k\to L,$ since the tensor product of the field extensions over $k$ equals $L$, which is a field.

Comment: Why did you add a hypothesis that already holds in the example that I explained?  In the example below, both field extensions $k(X)\to k(Y)$ and $k(X)\to k(Z)$ are isomorphisms.

Comment: What is $\eta_Z$?

Comment: For anybody who reads the problem and is puzzled about the mismatch with the answer below: the OP has already modified the question twice (I answered the first modification, and then the OP modified the question a second time).

Comment: Can anybody else please explain what $\eta_Z$ is?

Answer (score 4):

**Edit.** I edited the post below to address the OP's (repeated) modifications of the question.

**Answer to original question without any hypothesis that $\mathcal{O}_X$ equals $\mathcal{O}_Y\cap \mathcal{O}_Z.$**
I am just posting my comment as an answer.  Let $X$ be an integral scheme that is not normal, e.g., $\text{Spec}\ k[u,v]/\langle u^2 - v^3\rangle$ for a field $k$ of characteristic $\neq 2,3$.  By a corollary of the Noether normalization theorem, the normalization morphism $\nu:X^{\text{nor}}\to X$ is a finite morphism.  Denote by $U\subset X$ the maximal open subscheme over which $\nu$ is flat, and denote by $C\subset X$ the closed complement of $X$.  By openness of the normal locus (should be in Section 24 of Matsumura, "Commutative Ring Theory"), since the generic point $\text{Spec}\ k(X)$ is normal, the open $U$ is dense.  Over $U$, the morphism $\nu$ is an isomorphism.  For every point $p\in C$, the fiber of $\nu$ over $p$ has length $\ell(p)\geq 2$.

Let both $f:Y\to X$ and $g:Z\to Y$ equal $\nu$.  Then $X^{\text{nor}}\times_X X^{\text{nor}}\to X$ is a finite morphism that is an isomorphism over $U$.  Since $\nu$ is finite, hence affine, it is separated.  Thus, the diagonal morphism, $$\Delta:X^{\text{nor}}\to X^{\text{nor}}\times_X X^{\text{nor}},$$ is a closed immersion.  In particular, when we restrict over the open $U$, this closed immersion is an isomorphism.  Hence, this closed immersion is one irreducible component of the reduced scheme of $X^{\text{nor}}\times_X X^{\text{nor}}$, and it is the unique irreducible component that intersects the inverse image of $U$.

However, the length of the fiber of $\Delta(X^{\text{nor}})$ over $p\in C$ equals $\ell(p)$, whereas the fiber of $X^{\text{nor}}\times_X X^{\text{nor}}$ equals $\ell(p)^2 > \ell(p)$.  Thus, the closed immersion $\Delta$ fails to be an isomorphism over every point of $C$.  So $X^{\text{nor}}\times_X X^{\text{nor}}$ is not integral.

In the example $X=\text{Spec}\ k[u,v]\langle u^2 - v^3\rangle$, the scheme $X^{\text{nor}}\times_X X^{\text{nor}}$ is irreducible but not reduced.  In the example $X=\text{Spec}\ k[u,v]/\langle u^2 - v^2(v-1) \rangle$, the scheme $X^{\text{nor}}\times_X X^{\text{nor}}$ is reducible (the extra irreducible components come from pairs of distinct points of $X^{\text{nor}}$ that are "separated apart" from branches of singularities of $X$).

**Answer to modified question with hypothesis that $\mathcal{O}_X$ equals $\mathcal{O}_Y\cap \mathcal{O}_Z.$**  All of the following rings will be algebras over the power series ring $k[[t]]$.  The schemes below are reduced and equidimensional, but not integral.  It is straightforward to find integral schemes that are finite type over $k$ and such that the schemes below are obtained via base change by $\text{Spec}\ \widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,p} \to X.$  For instance, this works for the plane curve $X=\text{Spec}\ k[u,v]/\langle v^3-(u^3+u^4)\rangle$ and the "triple point" $p=\langle u,v\rangle.$

Let $A$ be $k[[t]]\times k[[t]]\times k[[t]].$  Denote by $e_1,$ $e_2,$ and $e_3$ the elements $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$.  Thus, $A$ is the finite $k[[t]]$-algebra, $$A=k[[t]][e_1,e_2,e_3]/\langle e_1^2-e_1,e_2^2-e_2,e^3_2-e_3, e_1+e_2+e_3-1, e_1e_2,e_1e_3,e_2e_3\rangle.$$

Let $\mathcal{O}_X,$ $\mathcal{O}_Y,$ and $\mathcal{O}_Z$ be the following $k$-subalgebras of $A,$ $$\mathcal{O}_X := k[[t]][te_1,te_2,te_3], \ \ \mathcal{O}_Y := k[[t]][e_1,te_2,te_3], \ \ \mathcal{O}_Z := k[[t]][te_1,te_2,e_3].$$  Thus, an element of $A$, $$a = (c_1 ,c_3,c_3) + tb, \ \ (c_1,c_2,c_3)\in k\times k \times k,\ \ b\in A,$$ is in $\mathcal{O}_X$, resp. $\mathcal{O}_Y$, resp. $\mathcal{O}_Z$, if and only if $c_1=c_2=c_3$, resp. $c_2=c_3$, resp. $c_1=c_2$.  The intersection of $\mathcal{O}_Y$ and $\mathcal{O}_Z$ in $A$ equals $\mathcal{O}_X$, i.e., if both $c_2$ equals $c_3$ and also $c_1$ equals $c_2$, then $c_1=c_2=c_3$.  Also, $\mathcal{O}_Y$ and $\mathcal{O}_Z$ generate $A$: the element $e_1$ is in $\mathcal{O}_Y$, the element $e_3$ is in $\mathcal{O}_Z$, and thus the element $e_2=1-(e_1+e_3)$ is in the subring that they generate.

As extensions of $\mathcal{O}_X$, the rings $\mathcal{O}_Y$, resp. $\mathcal{O}_Z$, equal, $$\mathcal{O}_Y \cong \mathcal{O}_X[f_1]/\langle f_1^2-f_1,tf_1-te_1\rangle,\ \  \mathcal{O}_Z \cong \mathcal{O}_X[f_3]/\langle f_3^2-f_3,tf_3-te_3\rangle.$$
For the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_X = \langle te_1,te_2,te_3 \rangle$ in $\mathcal{O}_X$ with residue field $k$, both of the fiber rings $\mathcal{O}_Y/\mathfrak{m}_X\cdot \mathcal{O}_Y$ and $\mathcal{O}_Z/\mathfrak{m}_X\cdot \mathcal{O}_Z$ have dimension $2$ as $k$-vector spaces, generated by $1$ and $f_1,$ resp. generated by $1$ and $f_3.$  Thus, the fiber ring $(\mathcal{O}_Y\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{O}_Z)/\mathfrak{m}_X\cdot (\mathcal{O}_Y\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{O}_Z)$ has dimension $4$ as a $k$-vector space, generated by $$ 1\otimes 1, \ \ 1\otimes f_3, \ \ f_1\otimes 1, \ \ f_1\otimes f_3.$$  On the other hand, $A/\mathcal{m}_X\cdot A$ has dimension $3$ as a $k$-vector space generated by $$1,\mathcal{e}_1, \mathcal{e}_3.$$   Thus, the kernel of the surjective $k[[t]]$-algebra homomorphism, $$\mathcal{O}_Y\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} \mathcal{O}_Z\to A,$$ is an ideal of length $1$.  Therefore $\mathcal{O}_Y\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{O}_Z$ is not an integral domain.

Explicitly, the kernel is generated by the element $f=f_1\otimes f_3.$  Note that this is an idempotent element, so $\mathcal{O}_Y\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{O}_Z$ has an extra irreducible component that does not dominate any irreducible component of $\mathcal{O}_X$.  In fact $f$ is annihilated by $t$ since $$t\cdot f = (tf_1)\otimes f_3 = (1\cdot te_1)\otimes f_3 = 1 \otimes (te_1\cdot f_3) = 1\otimes 0 = 0.$$

Comment: If we write $R \colon= k[T] \otimes_{k[u,v]/(u^2 - v^3)} k[T]$, with the embedding $u \mapsto T^3, v \mapsto T^2$. What is the nilpotent element in R?

Comment: For notation's sake, I will denote by $a$ and $b$ the elements $T\otimes 1$ and $1\otimes T.$  Then $R$ equals $k[a,b]/\langle a^2-b^2,a^3-b^3\rangle.$  Thus, the element $n=a-b$ is nilpotent.  Indeed $n^3 = (a-b)^3 = a^3-3a^2b+3ab^2-b^3 = a^3 -3(b^2)b + 3a(a^2) - b^3 = 2(a^3-b^3) = 0.$

Comment: Maybe $4(a^3 - b^3)$ but NOT $2(a^3 - b^3)$.

Comment: Under the modified assumption ${\cal O}_Y \cap {\cal O}_Z = {\cal O}_X$, there should be *NO* example.

Comment: I wonder why, as stated in the above answer, the closed immersion $\Delta$ failing to be an isomorphism over a every point of $C$, which is non regular locus of ${\mathrm Spec}\,k[u,v]/(u^2 - v^3)$, implies that $X^{\mathrm{nor}} \times_X X^{\mathrm{nor}}$ is *not* integral. Is this some standard fact in scheme theory?

Answer (score 1):

The assumption $\mathcal O_Y\cap\mathcal O_Z=\mathcal O_X$ needs to be made more precise. In order for the intersection $\mathcal O_Y\cap\mathcal O_Z$ of two rings to make sense, they must both be contained in some larger set. This larger set must be specified here. One option is to consider $\mathcal O_Y$ and $\mathcal O_Z$ as subrings of $\mathcal O_Y\otimes_{\mathcal O_X}\mathcal O_Z$. But then the condition $\mathcal O_Y\cap\mathcal O_Z=\mathcal O_X$ is satisfied, so the above example of Jason Starr still applies.

If $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ happen to be integral and the maps $f$ and $g$ happen to be birational, as in Jason Starr's example, then we can take the intersection $\mathcal O_Y\cap\mathcal O_Z$ inside their common field of fractions. This more restricted setting rules out Jason Starr's example.